# how to define foreign key constraint in ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I want define foreign key constraint in ActiveRecord for example, user.id to article.user_id.

On deleting a user, What I know so far is:  `User::afterDelete()`(afterSave) or handle event `ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_DELETE`(EVENT_AFTER_SAVE).

another way is using database's foreign key constraint to do this.

Does Yii2 provide a better way to do this?

Comment: is there a reason afterDelete or database constraints don't fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use migration or migration command.
In Yii2 migration    [`Class yii\db\Migration`](http://Class%20yii%5Cdb%5CMigration)  there is the [`addForeignKey()`](http://addForeignKey()) coomand 
this commandi  builds a SQL statement for adding a foreign key constraint to an existing table.

eg:

```
 $this->addForeignKey('fk1', 'table1', 'foreign_id', 'table2', 'id','CASCADE','CASCADE');
```

Comment: yeah, I just forget to mention it in the question desc.

Comment: If it this what you are looking for or if this is useful for you please rate it and or check as accepted. Otherview please explain better your question

Comment: it's a solution, but not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use your DBMS to verify foreign key integrity (for example, if your underlying DBMS is MySQL with MyISAM tables), the way to enforce it is using the ["unique" validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#unique).

This validator allow you to check if a certain model exists in your db. For example, if you have a `Book` that has exactly one `Author`, add the following to `Book`'s `rules()`:

```
['author_id', 'exist', 'targetClass' => Author::className(), 'targetAttribute' => 'id'],
```

This validator is also useful to create more complex conditions, like "Book's author must exist and also have Rating more than N".